# Why do apostrophes (" ' ") turn into ▒'s when reading from a file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I used Bash to open a Python file. The Python file should read a utf-8 file and display it in the terminal. It gives me a bunch of ▒'s ("Aaron▒s" instead of "Aaron's"). Here's the code:

```
# It reads text from a text file (done).
f = open("draft.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
    # It handles apostrophes and non-ASCII characters.
    print(f.read())
```

I've tried different combinations of:

- read formats with the open function ("r" and "rb")
- strip() and rstrip() method calls
- decode() method calls
- text file encoding (specifically ANSI, Unicode, Unicode big endian, and UTF-8).

It still doesn't display apostrophes (" ' ") properly. How do I make it display apostrophes instead of ▒'s?

Comment: Try `print(repr(f.read()))` to see what's actually there - probably some Unicode apostrophe-ish character that isn't supported by your terminal.

Comment: I doubt this is actually an apostrophe. When you copy and paste text from programs like MS Word and Mac's TextEdit, apostrophes aren't actually apostrophes. Another thing you can try apart from what @jasonharper recommended above is to use Unix's `xxd` command. It will print out the hex code of all characters. If it's a true apostrophe, the hex code should read `27`. See: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @jasonharper  repr(f.read()) still gives the ▒'s, but you're right. After doing the xxd command like entpnerd suggested, it returned 92 (’) instead of 27 ('). It's a right-slanting apostrophe that I copied from Google Drive text (draft.txt contains a paragraph from a Google Doc). Juxtaposed in the same notepad document, they look different. Bash doesn't support the right-slanting apostrophe character (or I haven't configured Bash to support it... which is more likely).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with Git Bash. If I switch to Powershell, Python displays the apostrophes (Aaron's) perfectly. The semantic read errors (Aaron▒s) appear only with  Git Bash. I'll give more details if I learn more about it.

Update: @jasonharper and @entpnerd suggested that the draft.txt apostrophe might be "apostrophe-ish" and not a legitimate apostrophe. I compared the draft.txt apostrophe (copy and pasted from a Google Doc) with an apostrophe directly entered. They look different (’ vs. '). In xxd, the value for the apostrophe-ish character is 92. An actual apostrophe is 27. Git Bash only supports the latter (unless there's just something I need to configure, which is more likely).

Second Update: Clarified that I'm using Git Bash. I wasn't aware that there were multiple terminals (is that the right way of putting it?) that ran Bash.

Comment: It is more likely the terminal session that you are using to run bash does not support the alien proprietary character set.  Bash itself is indifferent to character sets except where you are using bash text manipulation, which you don't appear to be doing.

Comment: What do you see with `env | grep -E 'LANG|LC_'`

Comment: @glennjackman I see "LANG=en_US.UTF-8". (Sorry for the late reply!) I researched several pages on character encoding/decoding. I didn't find anything that would magically determine the encoding, but if I got the character from a Google Doc, I think it's UTF-8. So, if ~94% of webpages use UTF-8, Powershell shows the character, and I got it from Google, it's probably UTF-8. If Bash says that it's using UTF-8 to encode text, now I'm really curious what's up.

Comment: This may be a terminal emulator issue. I see you mention powershell, so you're on windows. What terminal program do you use for bash? It may be *that* GUI does not handle wide chars properly. I use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) for WSL which doesn't seem to have any difficulties.

Comment: @glennjackman I use Git Bash. I just pasted " ’ vs. ' " into Git Bash, and it showed on screen. Would it still be the terminal emulator if I'm able to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm out. I don't have any more suggestions for you. Posting a screenshot or 2 may help others.

Comment: Ok. Your input was great, and I hope you have a great day.